# append a text string to the left of all the cells of a column in excel 2002?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have two columns with two values.. I want to append some text to the left of all the cells of Column A and concatenate to the right of all the cells of Column B.

Basically I'm trying to avoid having to type in a whole bunch of sql updates. so for example if i have  an excel with

ID Employee Name

135     Rasputin
76      Bush

I want to generate something like this

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET ID = '135', WHERE employee_name= 'RASPUTIN'
UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET ID = '76', WHERE employee_name= 'BUSH'
```

So perhaps a solution of appending text to the cells and then merging the rows?

I prefer a built in function as I'm not familiar with VBA thanks!

Comment: What SQL/Server version? DB2/MSSQL/Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming ID is in in Column A
and Employee Name is in Column B

Try this:
="UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET ID = '" & A1 & "' WHERE EMPLOYEE = '" & B1 & "'"

in column C row one and then copy the contents of the cells down to generate SQL for each update.

**Note:** there's no comma before the WHERE.